# Efficient way of sending a large number of images from client to server

Tags: python, image, sockets, opencv, gstreamer

I'm working on a project where one client needs to take several snapshots from a camera (i.e. it's actually taking a short-duration video, hence a stream of frames), then **send all images to a server** which then performs some processing on these images and returns a result to the client.

Client and server are all running *Python3* code.

The critical part is the image sending one.

Some background first, images are *640*480 jpeg* files. JPEG was chosen as a default choice, but lower quality encoding can be selected as well. They are captured in sequence by a camera. We have thus approximately *~600 frames* to send. Frame size is around 110KiB.

The client consists of a Raspberry Pi 3 model B+. It sends the frames via wifi to a 5c server. Server and client both reside in the same LAN for the prototype version. But future deployments might be different, both in term of connectivity medium (wired or wireless) and area (LAN or metro).

I've implemented several solutions for this:

1. Using **Python sockets** on the server and the client: I'm either sending *one frame directly* after one frame capture, or I'm sending *all images in sequence* after the whole stream capture is done.
2. Using **Gstreamer**: I'm launching a GStreamer endpoint on my client and directly send the frames to the server as I stream. I'm capturing the stream on the server side with OpenCV compiled with GStreamer support, then save them to the disk.

Now, the issue I'm facing is that even if both solutions work 'well' (they get the 'final' job done, which is to send data to a server and receive a result based on some remote processing), I'm convinced there is *a better way* to send a large amount of data to a server, using either the Python socket library, or any other available tools.

All personal researches are done on that matter lead me to solutions similar to mine, using Python sockets, or were out of context (relying on other backends than pure Python).

By a better way, I assume:

1. A solution that **saves bandwidth** as much as possible.
2. A solution that **sends all data as fast as possible**.

For 1. I slightly modified my first solution to archive and compress all captured frames in a .tgz file that I send over to the server. It indeed decreases the bandwidth usage but also increases the time spent on both ends (due to the un/compression processes). It's obviously particularly true when the dataset is large.

For 2. GStreamer allowed me to have a negligible delay between the capture and the reception on my server. I have however no compression at all and for the reasons stated above, I cannot really use this library for further development.

How can I send a large number of images from one client to one server with minimal bandwidth usage and delay in Python?

Comment: Are you on a Raspberry Pi or a supercomputer? Are you sending over wifi or wired Ethernet? How big are your JPEG files in bytes? Could you accept lower quality JPEG encoding?

Comment: Thanks. I added additional information in the original post.

Comment: Are you currently taking advantage of the fact that your Raspberry Pi has 4 cores? I have generally found I can get good performance by letting one core/thread do solely acquisition as fast as possible and then running 1-3 cores/threads for processing/transmission. Also consider running two parallel threads sending images on via sockets to the remote machine so you can use the full wifi bandwidth.

Comment: Excellent advice indeed. I'm not using the 4 cores, so I can theoretically do acquisition with one, then spinoff two processes on two different cores for frame sending (even / uneven frames). It would be quite useful if I perform processing one frame at a time, but in my case, I can wait for the full frame sequence to be sent first. Keeping the suggestion for future projects though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to transfer images as frames you can use some existing apps like [MJPEG-Streamer](https://github.com/jacksonliam/mjpg-streamer) which encode images from a webcam interface to `JPG` which reduces the image size. But if you need a more robust transfer with advanced encoding you can use some Linux tools like `FFMPEG` with streaming which is documented in [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide).

If you want lower implementation and control the whole stream by your code for modifications you can use web-based frameworks like `Flask` and transfer your images directly throw HTTP protocol. You can find a good example in [here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask).

If you don't want to stream you can convert a whole set of images to a video encoded format like `h264` and then transfer bytes throw the network. You can use `opencv` to do this.
There are also some good libraries written in python like [pyffmpeg](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyffmpeg/).

Comment: MJPEG-Streamer is a standalone app, as far as I can tell from the doc, and I would like to avoid external programs in the solution. Similarly for Flask, even if the lib is pure Python, adding another protocol to the stack (http) looks a bit overkill to me (personal opinion, I'm pretty sure it would achieve the goal just fine). Pyffmpeg looked promising but it seems like the project hasn't been maintained for a long time. However, merging frames with opencv using h264 seems to be the perfect option for me. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

you can restream camera using ffmpeg over network so that client can read it both ways. it will reduce delays.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31044133)